# Remove objects from a list through an array of integers?

Tags: java, arrays, list

Hi community I have a question, I happen to have an array of objects loaded on startup, through that generate array another array of integers that contains your code, it appears that array of integers'm removing their values, what I want is to compare the list of integer array currently have with the array of objects, and remove all code object that whole array mentioned is found.

My code java:

```
private List<ValidColumnKey> columnCustomer; 
private int[] selectedCustomer;

public void init(){
    this.setColumnCustomer(new ArrayList<ValidColumnKey>());        
    this.getColumnCustomer().add(new ValidColumnKey(1, "Codigo", "code"));  
    this.getColumnCustomer().add(new ValidColumnKey(2, "Nombre", "name"));  
    this.getColumnCustomer().add(new ValidColumnKey(3, "Nombre Comercial", "comercialName"));  
    this.getColumnCustomer().add(new ValidColumnKey(4, "Estado", "isActive")); 

    this.setSelectedCustomer(new int [this.getColumnCustomer().size()]);
    int i = 0;
    for(ValidColumnKey column : this.getColumnCustomer()){
        this.getSelectedCustomer()[i] = column.getCodigo();
        i++;
    }
}
```

I mean I would have my array of integers with codes removed, like this:

```
selectedCustomer = [1, 2, 3];
```

What I wanted was to remove from the list of objects that do not have codes in the array of integers, but it is not my code:

```
List<ValidColumnKey> auxRemoColumnKeys = new ArrayList<ValidColumnKey>();
for(ValidColumnKey column : this.getColumnCustomer()){
    for(Integer codigo : this.getSelectedCustomer()){
        if (column.getCodigo() != codigo) {
            auxRemoColumnKeys.add(column);
            break;
        }
    }           
}
this.getColumnCustomer().remove(auxRemoColumnKeys);
```

I could guide the solution.

Comment: I am very confused what your question is... what is the input / output

Comment: Hello friend in the public method init (), it will load the values ​​of the two lists (Objects and integers), after a process remove some values ​​from the list of integers, and these values ​​are removed I remove them from the list of objects. The output is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.getColumnCustomer().remove(auxRemoColumnKeys);
```

This statement assumes you have a valid `equals` method for your class `ValidColumnKey`, which I suspect is probably not the case.

What you want to do is iterate with a `Iterator`. Some sample code could be like

```
Set<Integer> toRemoveCodes = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
for (Iterator<ValidColumnKey> it = this.getColumnCustomer().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
   ValidColumnKey curColumnKey = it.next();
   Integer code = curColumnKey.codigo();
   if (toRemoveCodes.contains(code)) {
       it.remove();
   } 

}
```

Comment: *"This statement assumes you have a valid equals method"* Object identity is adequate for this because the OP is adding items to the removal list that originate from the source list itself.

Comment: @Radiodef Correct. Everything would work as expected if the OP had used `removeAll` , removed the `break` statement and the `codigo` for loop. But just looking at the code, wouldn't you expect to have an `equals` method ?

Comment: The equals distinction doesn't matter here. If you want to remove a specific object from a list and you have a reference to that object identify is adequate (and probably desired).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons your current attempt is failing. The first is that this line:

```
if (column.getCodigo() != codigo) {
```

Is testing for object equivalence between `Integer`s, not value equavalence between `int`s. If you want to compare `Integer`s, you have to use the equals method:

```
if (!column.getCodigo().equals(codigo)) {
```

However, if `getCodigo` returns an `int` and `getSelectedCustomer` returns an `int[]` then this line should be changed instead:

```
for(int codigo : this.getSelectedCustomer()){
```

Because you didn't need to use `Integer` in the first place.

Secondly, this line attempts to remove auxRemoColumnKeys itself so you probably mean `removeAll`:

```
this.getColumnCustomer().remove(auxRemoColumnKeys);
```

Lastly, your logic is generally flawed. It basically says *"for each element in getColumnCustomer, if getCodigo is not equal to all of getSelectedCustomer remove it"*. I don't think that's what you've intended.

This is a modified loop that uses the same "add to a list and remove the list items" procedure but the logic will work:

```
List<ValidColumnKey> auxRemoColumnKeys = new ArrayList<ValidColumnKey>();
int[] selected = this.getSelectedCustomer();

for (ValidColumnKey column : this.getColumnCustomer()) {
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < selected.length; i++) {

        /* note: if getCodigo returns an Integer change this check to
         * "if (column.getCodigo().equals(selected[i])) {"
         */
        if (column.getCodigo() == selected[i]) {
            break;
        }
    }

    /* this says "if the search loop did not break early" */
    if (i == selected.length) {
        auxRemoColumnKeys.add(column);
    }
}
this.getColumnCustomer().removeAll(auxRemoColumnKeys);
```

Comment: The OP just wants to remove ids. The ids need not be sorted. This won't work for unsorted ids. `removeAll` will probably lead to a time complexity of O(n**2) and finding out ids probably takes another O(n**2) in worst case.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about sorted/unsorted, though my code had an error too (oops). About time complexity, I might personally do this a different way, but I don't think it teaches anything to just say "your way has errors, so here is another way". Handing a solution that's vastly different solves a problem but is more like a shortcut and doesn't show somebody how to come up with solutions on their own.

Comment: Ok, you corrected the error. Sorry, if I sounded rude. About complexity, let's assume OP had a list where the `ValidColumnKey` ids  are in descending order and the ids to remove are in ascending order. So the first element to remove is at the end of the list and the second element to remove is at the second last position and so on. So when you add up the steps - it comes out to be:n + (n-1) + (n-2) + .. 3 + 2 + 1 = O(n**2). `removeAll` also works in the same way.

Comment: @bsd `removeAll` actually does the whole removal basically in one pass (or at least [the OpenJDK one does](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.batchRemove%28java.util.Collection%2Cboolean%29)--*future note: link could be broken*). So the lowest time complexity would be to use a HashSet for the integers and a HashSet for the removals. That would be one pass to find the removals and one pass to remove. But I basically don't find it to matter too much since the list is small in this case.

Comment: `contains` takes O(n) time. So the final complexity is still O(n**2)

Comment: @bsd It won't for a HashSet. But then ValidColumnKey would have to override hashCode and equals. ; )